# Azure DevOps pipeline error - The value of parameter linuxProfile.ssh.publicKeys.keyData is invalid

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I created a ARM template for automatic AKS creation and/or updates. I generated a RSA public key using the Azure bash command line and entered it in the ARM template. I use the template in an Azure DevOps pipeline. Deployment failes. with the error message:

```
[error]InvalidParameter: Provisioning of resource(s) for container service aks-openfaas-test-0619 in resource group rg-openfaas--test-0619 failed. Message: {
  "code": "InvalidParameter",
  "message": "The value of parameter linuxProfile.ssh.publicKeys.keyData is invalid. Please see https://aka.ms/aks-naming-rules for more details.",
  "target": "linuxProfile.ssh.publicKeys.keyData"
 }. Details:  undefined
```

I followed the Microsoft instruction on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/mac-create-ssh-keys.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add more information to help with reproducibility for others. You might follow this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/680) addressing a similar error message. Chances are you are facing a similar problem.

Comment: Does it work when you deploy from New-AzResourceGroupDeployment ? I've got the same problem if it does...

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when trying to use in AKS node pools.

Add `\n` at the end. The content of the pub file was like below, replace `windowsuser@computername` with `\n` in the json.

```
ssh-rsa ***Key*** windowsuser@computername
"linuxProfile": {
                    "adminUsername": "azureuser",
                    "ssh": {
                      "publicKeys": [
                        {
                            "keyData": "ssh-rsa *****Key*****\n"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to create new VMs using Azure templates

in my case I had to add a few more `\n` not only one at the end of the key.

If you have a Public SSH key in a format like this:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20200611"
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

Once you copy and paste this into the template field: `Admin Public Key * :`

I finally got it working if you replace at least four new lines with `\n` and remove any extra spaces inside the random generated key.

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----\nComment: \"rsa-key-20200611\"\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF==\n---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----\n
```

Another other option is, if you want to keep it exactly following same format, then you can replace any space character `' '` inside the key for `'\n'` as well.

Once you do this the format of the key will be correct and you will get the VMs properly created using templates. That is a common copy paste problem replacing new line characters for just a regular space character.